# cordova-plugin-qrscanner: error: no suitable constructor found for DefaultDecoderFactory(ArrayList<BarcodeFormat>,<null>,<null>)

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to compile a project using the native Cordova QR Scanner plugin, however I keep getting this error. From what I understand, this is an issue with the way the code is written, and its sending the wrong values to the constructor, or just not finding the constructor in the first place. So how am I supposed to fix this? Am I just missing some files, or perhaps something is wrong with my environment (all I used was "npm install", "ionic cordova prepare", and then I installed the plugin and added Android as a platform)? I found [a question](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/issues/322) on GitHub from someone with the same problem, but its unanswered at the moment.

Comment: Your plugin is neither native nor official, it was created by "bitpay" and it's bugged.

Comment: I see, my mistake. Thank you. Any idea what the issue with the plugin here is?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) which I use perfectly fine with cordova@9.0.0 and cordova-android@8.1.0.

The following barcode types are currently supported:

[image]

PS: there is no such thing as a *native Cordova QR Scanner plugin*. Plugins are not native, they might be *official* when they are created by Apache, but this is not the case (your plugin was created by certain *bitpay* staff)

Comment: I'm sorry, I cant use that. There's a conflict with an SDK I'm using from the company I'm developing for. I'm already working to solve that one with the company, but in the meantime I'm trying to get help for the one I mentioned here.